# How to get value of generator

Tags: javascript, typescript, generator

scenario.ts

```
export interface Step {
    text: string;
    image: string;
    time: number
}

export interface IScenario {
    name: string;

    steps: Array<Step>;
}
```

Restaurant.ts

```
import {IScenario, Step} from './interfaces/scenario'

export default class Restaurant implements IScenario {
    name: string = 'Приключение в ресторане';

    steps: Array<Step> = [
        {
            text: 'Вы пришли в ресторан',
            image: 'https://sun9-3.userapi.com/55H3n5pt-TvwwdQzmpBZ9mcHURCqf85x1mXvlw/oyI4OlFu3R0.jpg',
            time: 2000,
        },
        {
            text: 'Перед вами стоит стол',
            image: '',
            time: 5000,
        },
    ];

    private *enumerateSteps(steps: Array<Step>): IterableIterator<Step> {
        yield step;
    }   

    start(): void {
        for (const step of this.enumerateSteps(this.steps)) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                return console.log(step.text);
                step.next();
              }, step.time);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get the next step after time, but get an error:

> Property 'next' does not exist on type 'Step'.

And I also have an error about the absence `step` for some reason, but I don't know why.

Comment: "*an error about the absence `step` for some reason*" - yes, there is no `step` variable defined in your `enumerateSteps` method. What did you expect it to be? Notice you're also not using the argument  `steps` anywhere. (But it doesn't appear to be a typo as they have different types).

Comment: I want to get the present `step` in each case. I tried to update the generator `const current = steps[0]; yield current;` but I still get the error "Property 'next' does not exist on type 'Step':

Comment: It looks like you're trying to asynchronously iterate over your generator. In this case, as @Bergi has noted, there's no need for one, but the language does allow for [async interators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/asyncIterator).

Comment: Bergi's answer is excellent, but another issue with your code - if you only `yield` once (not in a loop) in a generator function, you only iterate once. In other words, `[...({ *[Symbol.iterator]() { yield 1 } })]` is just `[1]`.

Comment: Thanks to all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be using generators here at all. What you want can either be done in a callback-based approach

```
start(callback?: () => void): void {
    this.steps.reduceRight((next, step) => () => {
        console.log(step.text);
        setTimeout(next, step.time);
    }, () => {
        console.log('All steps done');
        callback?.();
    })();
}
```

or with promises and `async`/`await`:

```
async start(): Promise<void> {
    for (const step of this.steps) {
        console.log(step.text);
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, step.time));
    }
    console.log('All steps done');
}
```